# Time calculation(addition) in php e.g -> '22:50:50' + '12:50:50'

Tags: php, datetime, sum, addition

my problem is when i make addition of two time then it only output hours
from 0-23. I need something that will output time as such:

150:0:0

to represent 150 hours, 0 minutes, and 0 seconds.

for example:

when i make '23:59:59'+ '01:40:40'

then it only output '00:40:40'

please help me guys.

thanks in advance

Comment: This problem is not correctly defined. How do you handle leap seconds? And why does `'23:59:59'+ '01:40:40'` not equal `'01:40:39'`?

Comment: Use `explode` to convert each string to three integers and add them together. After that do some arithmetic (divide by 60 etc) to convert totals like 121 minutes to 2 hours and 1 minute.

Comment: but how i get 23:59:59'+ '01:40:40 addition in only minute??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$a=explode(':','23:59:59');
$t1=$a[0]*3600+$a[1]*60+$a[2];

$a=explode(':','01:40:00');
$t2=$a[0]*3600+$a[1]*60+$a[2];

$t3=$t1+$t2;

$h=floor($t3/3600);
$m=floor(($t3%3600)/60);
$s=$t3-$h*3600-$m*60;

echo $h.':'.$m.':'.$s;
```

Comment: It's work but here problem is when i do $t2-$t1 then it gives minus value.